# How to prevent Sentry from grouping errors/alerts on a specific type of error?

Tags: python, django, sentry, raven

I am trying to prevent sentry from grouping my errors. Specifically I log to sentry (`captureMessage()`) when a task is taking too long. A daemon will check this task on a regular interval. As long as the job is still "taking too long", I want it to alert me. As of now, I have I have one sentry alert where there are 10k events. Instead, I want each of these events to be an individual Sentry alert. I cannot find anything that would work. The closest thing I can find is [this link](https://docs.sentry.io/data-management/event-grouping/sdk-fingerprinting/?platform=python#group-errors-more-granularly). However, this does not help because I am not "splitting" these errors in to further subcategories; I simply do not want grouping to be enabled for this one particular section of my code (where I check task X).

Is this possible to do in Sentry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the fingerprint to a completely random value to create one group per event/message. That would effectively give you one alert per event/message.